# Automated creation of multiple datasets in Python-Pytables

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, append, data-science, pytables

In my script, I create several datasets manually:

```
    import tables
    dset1 = f.create_earray(f.root, "dataset1", atom=tables.Float64Atom(), shape=(0, 2))
    dset2 = f.create_earray(f.root, "dataset2", atom=tables.Float64Atom(), shape=(0, 2))
    dset3 = f.create_earray(f.root, "dataset3", atom=tables.Float64Atom(), shape=(0, 2))
    ...
```

I want to achieve two things:

1. Automate the above statements to execute in a loop fashion and create any desired (N) datasets
2. Then I also use `.append` method sequentially (as given below) which I also want to automate:

   ```
    dset1.append(np_array1) 
    dset2.append(np_array2) 
    dset3.append(np_array3) 
    ...
   ```

Will appreciate any assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to provide specific advice without more details. If you already have the NumPy arrays, you can create the EArray with the data in a single call (using the `obj=` parameter). Here's a little code snippet that shows how do do this in a loop.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

with tb.File('SO_64397597.h5','w') as h5f:
    
    arr1  = np.ones((10,2))
    arr2  = 2.*np.ones((10,2))
    arr3  = 3.*np.ones((10,2))
    arr_list = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
    for cnt in range(1,4):
        h5f.create_earray("/", "dataset"+str(cnt), obj=arr_list[cnt-1])
```

The code above doesn't create dataset objects. If you need them, you can access programmatically with this call:

```
# input where as path to node, name not required
ds = h5f.get_node("/dataset1")
# or
# input where as path to group, and name as dataset name
ds = h5f.get_node("/","dataset1")
```

If you don't have the arrays when you create the datasets, you can create the EArrays in the first loop, then add the np.array data in a second loop. See below:

```
with tb.File('SO_64397597.h5','w') as h5f:
    
    for cnt in range(1,4):
        h5f.create_earray("/", "dataset"+str(cnt), atom=tables.Float64Atom(), shape=(0, 2))

        # get array data...
        arr_list = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
        # add array data
        for cnt in range(1,4):
            h5f.get_node("/","dataset"+str(cnt)).append(arr_list[cnt-1])
```

Comment: Awesome. So I do not have arrays at creation time and following the last block (code) of your answer. How do I refer to the created datasets to append? For example, if you look at my question above, I refer them as `dset1`, `dset2`... I tried `name = f'dset{cnt}'` and then `name = h5f.create_earray...`but that didn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: If you know the dataset name, you can use `h5f.get_node(where,name)` returns the object by that name.  `where` can be the complete path (`name` not required) OR `where` can be the group path, and `name` is required. This gets the dataset where the name is dataset_{cnt}: `h5f.get_node("/","dataset"+str(cnt))`